# Combine columns a, b, c if column x is duplicate record - SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm not sure if I'm asking this right, but I am trying to have 1 row contain all the data for each "policy". The problem is, only 1 "insured name" is given per row.

Example table:
[image]

I need to get the following result:
[image]

How would I go about doing this?

---EDIT---
If there is only one insured, I would want insuredName2 to be NULL

Comment: are you wanting to eliminate the records and combine the results changing table structure and data in it or would a view / query which returns the desired results be more what you're after?

Comment: @anton brings up a good point.  What names do you want in insuredname1 and insurnamed2 if there are more than 2 insured under the same policy?

Comment: No, I don't want to eliminate the records that exist. I just need to take the resulting data and export it to a .csv file. In this case, there can be any number of insureds. Basically, I just need to end up with 1 row per policy number, which can contain x number of insureds. Most commonly either 1 or 2, but could potentially be more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added effective date to the query as I could see a composite primary key including both policy number and effective date.

This assumes a view on the data would be acceptable with changing existing table structure and data.

```
 SELECT a.PolicyNumber, a.effecitveDate a.insuredName as InsuredName1,   
        b.insuredName as InsuredName2
 FROM table a 
 INNER JOIN table b 
   ON a.policyNumber = b.policyNumber
  and A.effectiveDate = b.effectiveDate
```

Be sure to change `table` to be your `tablename` having this data.

Also if you want to ensure one way matches only have `and a.insuredName > B.InsuredName` on the join.  This was added to this per an excellent comment by jbrooks.

Comment: For a policy with 2 insureds, this is resulting with there being 1 row with the same name (John) for the columns InsuredName1 and InsuredName2, followed by a 2nd row with the result I'm after (InsuredName1 = John & InsuredName2 = Jane). For a policy with only 1 insured, this results with the row having the sole insured in both the InsuredName1 and InsuredName2 columns.

Comment: You also need "and a.insuredName > b.insuredName" else you will get "John", "Jane" and "Jane", John"

Comment: When selecting InsuredName2, I used a case statement to set InsuredName2 to NULL if it matches InsuredName1. Thanks to you all for the push in the right direction. `CASE WHEN b.insuredName <> InsuredName1 then b.InsuredName else null end as InsuredName2`

Comment: @DustinN. jbrooks has a good idea as well by using his approach you eliminate the need for case.

Comment: @xQbert I have tried implementing that, however, it eliminates all the policies where InsuredName2 is NULL, so it only returns the policies with 2 insureds

Comment: change the `inner join` to a `left Join` and change `a.insuredName > coalesce(B.InsuredName, a.insuredName)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use the following in some fashion:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.insuredName, b.insuredName 
    FROM table a 
    INNER JOIN table b 
     ON a.policyNumber = b.policyNumber
```

if effective date is also a consideration:

```
    ...
    On a.policyNumber = b.policyNumber
    And a.effectiveDate = b.effectiveDate;
```

Comment: effectiveDate may matter as well (need to be on join). depending on the key of table.  I could see Jon Doe not being married in Jan 1 of 2015 then marries Jane in 2015 and in Jan 1 2016 she's also on the same policy.

Comment: True. I also just assumed that two people were the max possible co-insured. Its true for the data provided but may not necessarily be the case edited answer.

Comment: You bring up a good point... how do we select the insured if there are more than 2?

Comment: You could use a subquery in the SELECT clause but it kind of nasty

Comment: Or perhaps multiple joins with wheres to match up all policy holders to the same policy number but not themselves

Comment: True but the question is more business related.. If they only want 2... which 2 do we select when more than 2 are present... How do we determine which two to use?  what rules can we implement to select the "correct 2"

Comment: I dont think that would be possible to determine with this schema. You would need a column to determine some sort of type like main or co insured.

Comment: As noted in xQbert's answer, for a policy with 2 insureds, this is resulting with there being 1 row with the same name (John) for the columns InsuredName1 and InsuredName2, followed by a 2nd row with the result I'm after (InsuredName1 = John & InsuredName2 = Jane). For a policy with only 1 insured, this results with the row having the sole insured in both the InsuredName1 and InsuredName2 columns.

Comment: add... WHERE a.insuredName <> b.insuredName to the end

Comment: You also need "and a.insuredName > b.insuredName".

Comment: If I add anything in the WHERE clause, my results would omit policies with only 1 insured, since all policies with only 1 insured result in the same name in both columns. I'm still wanting to see those policies as well, I just need a way to make the InsuredName2 column NULL if it matches the InsuredName1 column. I think I figured out how to do that with a CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have an unlimited number if names I would concatenate them all into a single column and then break it out again when I loaded it. I don't know Netezza but this is how you would do it in SQL Server:

```
        SELECT PolicyNumber,
               InsuredDate,  
               STUFF(
                    (
                     SELECT ';'+ a.Path 
                     FROM Insured a 
                     WHERE t.PolicyNumber = a.PolicyNumber 
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ),1,1,'')  AS InsuredNames
        FROM (SELECT PolicyNumber, 
                     MIN(InsuredDate) AS InsuredDate 
              FROM Insured 
              GROUP BY PolicyNumber) t
```

Comment: I get an error trying to implement this that says "found "XML" (at char 170) expecting `READ'". Surely it's something to do with the Netezza, I'm just not able to find anything on the error after some quick searching. I'll keep trying though.

Comment: You need to look into how Netezza allows you to concatenate items from different rows. It might not be with XML like SQL Server does.